# Image not acting "responsive" using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am pretty new to HTML/CSS and have begun trying to learn CSS flexbox layout. Just working on a simple site recreation from scratch using flexbox.

In full screen, the image positioning on the logo looks good. However, when shifting around the screen size, my nav bar on the right side responds but the logo image on the left does not. I believe I have set it up correctly though.

```
.header-container {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
 }


.header-container .logo .sb{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 width: 60%;
 position: relative;
 left: 50px;
 padding: 20px;
 }
```

Here's a link to my work as well: https://codepen.io/gkunthara/pen/VWdrYj

What exactly am I doing wrong? Any tips on the type of positioning I'm doing with flexbox or with flexbox, in general, are appreciated!

Comment: better solution is to use media queries

Comment: @Hash This has nothing to do with media queries.

Comment: @Terry yes as i said a better solution is media queries meant if u want the site to be compatible with any device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove position on `nav` & set `max-width: 100%` on logo image.

https://codepen.io/thesumit67/pen/bRKYLx?editors=1100

Comment: what does the @media exactly mean? Looks great though! Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Remove Position

```
.header-container .nav-bar-container {
    display: flex;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*right: 100px;*/
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. To elabourate on the reason why, that is because by using `position: absolute` OP is effectively taking the entire nav menu out of the layout, so the flexbox will see it has having zero width. p/s: I also suggest avoid using `position: relative` to give OP's logo left padding. Why not use `padding-left` instead?

Comment: logo will get smaller when resize to the smallest?

Comment: So when using flexbox positioning try to avoid position:relative and position: absolute code? Use margin/padding commands instead?